# 301 Redirect From One Domain/Directory to a New Domain outside of a directory?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've never done this before and need to make sure I don't mess it up.. add that to the fact that I hardly know what I am doing, and I am a bit stressed out over this.

I have a Drupal site that needs to redirect to a WP site. All of the posts in a particular category will need to redirect to the WordPress site... but they will not be redirecting to a particular category or directory.

**Knowing what I know about robots.txt files (which are likely totally different), I am thinking this would look like this:**
old.domain.com/latest-posts/* redirects to new.domain.com/

**Another example would be:**
old.domain.com/latest-posts/post-blog-title redirects to new.domain.com/post-blog-title

Whats the best way of doing this? Theres tons of options.. editing an htaccess file seems simple enough as long as I know what needs to be added. I've been referred to regex a bunch when researching this and regex makes me nervous for some reason.

Reference: https://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection
https://www.semrush.com/blog/301-redirect-htaccess/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following redirect in your `htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^latest-posts/(.*)$ https://new.example.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

This will 301 redirect all your `latest-posts` URLs to the new domain , ie: `olddomain.com/latest-posts/foo-bar` to `newdomain.com/foobar` .
Make sure to place this code at the top of your htaccess, and if you use WordPress then this code must be placed before the wp-rewrites in htaccess.

You can also use a simple 301 redirect instead of the above `RewriteRule` if the newdomain is on a different server or it's pointing to a different document root on the same server

```
 Redirect 301 /latest-posts/ https://newdomain.com/
```